# Preventing selection of certain items in Winforms ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have seen some questions similar to this, but they seem to be for WPF (which I'm not familiar with, and the solution doesn't appear applicable to me). I have an OwnerDrawFixed listbox (well, 2 actually) that I use to draw horizontal separator items if an added item is `""`. What I want is to skip over these completely when either clicked on (I've had trouble with click-dragging over the item selecting it) or selected via the up/down arrow keys. Here is my `DrawItem` event:

```
private void ListBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index < 0)
        return;

    e.DrawBackground();
    e.Graphics.DrawString((sender as ListBox).Items[e.Index].ToString(), (sender as ListBox).Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds);

    //Draw as a separator if there is no text
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((sender as ListBox).Items[e.Index].ToString()))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.DarkGray), new Point(e.Bounds.X + 5, e.Bounds.Y + 7), new Point(e.Bounds.X + e.Bounds.Width - 5, e.Bounds.Y + 7));
    }
    //Doesn't appear to do anything e.DrawBackground isn't..?
    //e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

I've tried combinations of the MouseUp, MouseDown, and SelectedIndexChanged events, either clearing the selection altogether (not great for arrow navigation for obvious reasons) or storing the previously selected index, determining the direction, and selecting the next value value (sometimes non-intuitive for clicking, if the items aren't close).
I also tried `myListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;`, but for some reason (perhaps something with my draw event?) it just highlights every item I select (without unselecting them).

Am I missing something if I'm trying to disallow selection of items where the item is an empty string?

Comment: Yeah... Not possible when you're working on an existing WinForms application.

Comment: @HighCore, what exactly does "winforms doesn't support customization" mean?  Let's not confuse visitors to this site.

Comment: @cdkMoose I've explained many times already, that a certain technology or framework "Foo" **"supporting"** a certain feature or capability "Bar", means that you can do or implement "Bar" using "Foo" **with relative ease**. Since you cannot actually customize *anything* in winforms *with relative ease*, then it can be said that winforms **doesn't support** customization. Yes you can implement horrid workarounds and hacks to achieve what you need to a certain extent, but the very existence of such workarounds and hacks proves my point.

Comment: @HighCore, so kind of you to have explained it many times already for us poor uneducated fools </satire>  But that is just your definition, not a solution to OPs problem.  I have read many times here and elsewhere that WPF has a steep learning curve, in my book "steep learning curve" does not equal "with relative ease", so I guess your definition means  WPF doesn't support customization either.  Why don't we stay away from opinions and disparaging remarks about technologies, instead let's just try to help OP with the problem he has presented.

Comment: @cdkMoose for the record, the OP's requirement can be achieved in WPF with 2 lines of XAML, which is clearly much easier than the horrendous hacks needed in winforms, demonstrated by the answers below.

Comment: And how does that help OP?  If it is necessary for him to work with WInForms, for whatever reason, your comment is not helping at all. The purpose of comments and answers should be to help OP and others who may be in a similar situation.

Comment: @cdkMoose, thank you. If I could use a wpf control in this product, I would at least try, despite the learning curve needed. That said, I cannot do this, for reasons beyond my control which I do not need to explain here. We can continue to bicker in chat, but otherwise these comments are extremely non-constructive for the issue as posted.

Comment: The fact that you have to touch WndProc and even use `DllImport` to do certain things in WinForms means that you’re bypassing the winforms API to do things. Even [mono has to implement the interface at the WndProc level](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/). This is indistinguishable from accessing private APIs via `System.Reflection`. If you have to do those things to access certain features with a certain framework, those features were never meant to be accessed. I.e., they’re not supported. Microsoft gave up and treats its private API as public for compatibility reasons, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution that works for me. I just added this one event to your posted code:

```
int lastIndex = 0;
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    int newIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
    if (s == "" )
    {
        if (newIndex > lastIndex && newIndex  < listBox1.Items.Count)
        {
            listBox1.SelectedIndex++;
        }
        else if (newIndex < lastIndex && newIndex > 0)
        {
            listBox1.SelectedIndex--;
        }
    }
    else lastIndex = newIndex;
}
```

Comment: This was actually causing issues for my double click event which removes and item (not mentioned in the post though, so it should in no way impact this answer). Solved it with an additional `MouseDown` to leverage your `lastIndex` variable.

Answer (score -1):

I modified the code from [ListBox with Disableable Items](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38017/ListBox-with-Disableable-Items) to suit your needs:

```
public class ListBoxEx : ListBox {

  private const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x200;
  private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
  private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
  private const int VK_LEFT = 0x25;
  private const int VK_UP = 0x26;
  private const int VK_RIGHT = 0x27;
  private const int VK_DOWN = 0x28;

  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    // Get params as int
    int lParam = m.LParam.ToInt32();
    int wParam = m.WParam.ToInt32();

    // Intercept mouse selection
    if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE || m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN) {
      Point clickedPt = new Point();
      clickedPt.X = lParam & 0x0000FFFF;
      clickedPt.Y = lParam >> 16;

      // If point is on a disabled item, ignore mouse
      for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Items[i].ToString()) &&
          GetItemRectangle(i).Contains(clickedPt))
          return;
    }

    // Intercept keyboard selection
    if (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
      if (wParam == VK_DOWN || wParam == VK_RIGHT) {
        // Select next enabled item
        for (int i = SelectedIndex + 1; i < Items.Count; i++)
          if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Items[i].ToString())) {
            SelectedIndex = i;
            break;
          }
        return;
      } else if (wParam == VK_UP || wParam == VK_LEFT) {
        // Select previous enabled item
        for (int i = SelectedIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--)
          if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Items[i].ToString())) {
            {
              SelectedIndex = i;
              break;
            }
          }
        return;
      }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
  }

  protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Index > -1) {
      string item = this.Items[e.Index].ToString();
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item)) {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.DarkGray, new Point(e.Bounds.X + 5, e.Bounds.Y + 7),
                                           new Point(e.Bounds.Right - 5, e.Bounds.Y + 7));
      } else {
        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected) {
          e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight, e.Bounds);
          TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, item, e.Font, e.Bounds, SystemColors.HighlightText);
        } else {
          e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
          TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, item, e.Font, e.Bounds, SystemColors.WindowText);
        }
      }
    }
    base.OnDrawItem(e);
  }
}
```